# Let's Advertise with Community Ads!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now that we're in Public Beta, it's time to start thinking of how to spread the word! Let's start this Beta off strong by creating our own ads. <sub>Forgive me as a I plagiarize a [post from 3D Printing](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/community-ads-lets-make-2d-ads-for-ourselves).</sub>

#### So what are these "Community Ads?"

Graduated sites allow the community to advertise relevant products or services within the site, using a system where the community chooses what to advertise. You can find these posts on per-site metas. Hint: these posts have the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag!

#### Cool! What should the ad be like?

There's a few requirements for these ads. Most notably,

- They must be 300px wide by 250px tall, or double for "retina" displays
- There's a limit on file size of 150 kB.
- The image must be hosted on i.stack.imgur (the Stack Exchange image hosting service).
- Ads must be GIF or PNG (no animated GIFs).

#### What else should I know?

To facilitate easy posting to other sites, make sure that the embedded image is of the following format:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

You can also include a message as a part of your answer with your own thoughts: why you chose some of the elements, and what sites the ads could potentially be posted to. Don't forget to critique each other as well!

---

Those are the rules, now it's up to us to make it happen! Let's have fun with it!

Comment: We already have some live and some on the way: http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/a/102/78 Although we can advertise better and more direct without the Area51 barrier now.

Comment: @Helmar Thank you for providing the link. I did see that post and that's what sparked the creation of this one. I think it will help to have this separate from the link you provided and make it easier for the Community Ads to accumulate here.

Answer (score 8):

I still like my sketch from the Christmas promo question.

> I used my unparalleled(ly bad) paint skills to make a sketch.
>
> [image: BestPaintSketchEverV2]

I'm making this Community Wiki. Everyone who is a better designer can gladly provide a better version of the picture that could be used as an actual Community Ad.

Comment: +1 Very clever!

Answer (score 8):

[image: Internet of Things Stack Exchange]

This ad is [tailored for Security Stack Exchange](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/community-promotion-ads-2017/2637#2637).

I made this in Gimp, XCF available on demand if someone has better design skills than me (which is about 99% of the world's population).

Comment: I like the tagline. Maybe we could use it with Aurora's draft - and post that specialised version at least to ITSEC.SE?

Comment: @Ghanima, here's this tagline on my design, if you're interested: http://i.imgur.com/gZeUqEd.png

Comment: What 'S' stands for, security? Can you elaborate why just S? What's the logic behind this.

Comment: @kenorb It builds on the joke “the S in IoT stands for security”, which is a riff on “the S in HTTPS stands for security”.

Answer (score 5):

**Note: please update all ads to use the high-resolution version if possible**.[image: Community Ad #1]

Here's my attempt at creating a reasonable looking community ad, ready for the 2017 Ad series. Turned out rather well in my opinion, but I'm open to any feedback, particularly on the **tagline**. If not, we can start sharing and voting on this ad immediately on other sites.

<sup>Based on the [Giftly pattern](https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/giftly/) from Subtle Patterns (CC BY-SA 3.0, by Hesam Keramati; remixed by myself, Aurora0001). The font used is [Nunito Regular](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito), if anyone's interested.</sup>

Template:

```
[![Internet of Things Stack Exchange][1]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzkJ2.png
[2]: http://iot.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: btw: this imgur link is probably not working when posting to the community ad threads at other metas. The image needs to be linked at the SE flavoured imgur, i.e. https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3cny.png

Comment: @Ghanima: Good catch; fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Links of IoT.SE 2017 Community Promotion Ad proposal Meta answers on any Stack Exchange site should be posted as an answer to this question to help the members of this community support the ads with their other accounts across Stack Exchange network.

Also we already have a list in this [post](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/where-can-we-get-more-subject-matter-experts/102#102) about 2016 Community Ads.

- Ad on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6085/56348). (Complete)
- Ad on [Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1265/63962). (Complete)
- Ad on [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/899/19949). (Complete)
- Ad on [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/a/12074/655923). (Complete)
- Ad on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8431/154764). (Complete)
- Ad on [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2635/138180). (Complete)
- Ad on [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2244/208017). (Complete)
- Ad on [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16691/606336). (Complete)
- Ad on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/community-promotion-ads-2017/4346#4346).
- Ad on [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/community-promotion-ads-2017/1894#1894). (Complete)
- Ad on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/community-promotion-ads-2017/4111#4111). (Complete)
- Ad on [Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/community-promotion-ads-2017/2970#2970). (Complete)

**Please upvote the respective meta posts!**

Comment: I will update my answer when the 2017 campaign has started.

Comment: The 2017 campaigns have just launched; feel free to update when you're ready.

Answer (score 2):

With the launch of the 2018 Community Ads series, it's time to think about how we're going to promote ourselves this year.

I'm planning to create some targeted ads for specific communities, and anyone else with an artistic inclination is invited to also try designing an ad. Feel free to post an answer with design ideas, or even completed products!

#### Ads for 2018

- None, yet!

<sup>Please update this as necessary — this answer is a collaborative wiki.</sup>