# Let's advertise with Community Ads! (2018)

Tags: discussion

Aurora posted an answer on the [existing Community Ads Post](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/lets-advertise-with-community-ads) from last year, mentioning that 2018 Community Ads season is in!  This is the chance for us as a community to propose and design creative "ads" to be advertised on graduated Stack Exchange sites!

#### What are the prerequisites for Community Ads?

- They must be 300px wide by 250px tall, or double for "retina" displays
- There's a limit on file size of 150 kB.
- The image must be hosted on i.stack.imgur (the Stack Exchange image hosting service).
- Ads must be GIF or PNG (no animated GIFs).

#### How do I post a Community Ad?

You can suggest ads in an answer to this question.  Others can comment and suggest improvements at need.  To facilitate reposting to graduated sites' community promotion area (hint: these posts are tagged [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads)), the embedded image should be posted in the following format:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: https://image-url
   [2]: https://clickthrough-url
```

#### Is there anything else?

With the embedded image, feel free to post comments in the answer, such as why you think this might be a good ad, or if the ad is designed for a specific site (ie., home improvement, mechanics, etc.).

I'm also posting an answer to this question to keep track of what sites we've posted what ads on, and how many votes are needed on those sites' metas to make the ad go live (6 total are needed).

**So let's get going!**  Make them *attractive,* make them *smart.*

<sub>N.B.: Much of this is stolen from the 2017 post, which was in turn stolen from [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/community-ads-lets-make-2d-ads-for-ourselves).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example I just developed:

[image: Internet of Things]

Comment: .SE sounds like a Swedish web site :)

Answer (score 4):

Links of IoT.SE 2018 Community Promotion Ad proposal Meta answers on any Stack Exchange site should be posted as an answer to this question to help the members of this community support the ads with their other accounts across Stack Exchange network.

- Ad on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6491/56348) (3/6)
- Ad on [Home Improvement](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1338/66007) (4/6)
- Ad on [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17724/527350) (1/6)

Also we already have a list in this [post](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/lets-advertise-with-community-ads) about 2017 Community Ads.

**Please upvote the respective meta posts!**